# When you select Product->Build (⌘B) in XCode, which version is built?

Tags: xcode

XCode has Build for Running/Testing/Profiling but also "Build". Does this build based on your last selection Run/Test/Profile, or does it default to one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode always uses the `Run` setup when building.

You can easily verify that it's not your latest selection: Choose "*Build For Profiling*", and you will see a `Release-{platformname}` folder in `Build/Products` within your derived data directory. Choose "*Build*" afterwards, and Xcode will not overwrite the `Release-{platformname}` directory but create another directory for Debug builds. This works under the assumption that you haven't changed the default schemes, which use Debug builds for the `Run` setup and Release builds for the `Profile` setup.

Likewise, you can change the `Run` setup to use the Release configuration, and when you simply build, you will see `Release-{platformname}` folders in the derived data directory.

The platform (name) is determined by your current selection:
[image]